# Stop playing HTML5 video on mouseout (lazy-load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Here is my project:  http://jsfiddle.net/p42q12cm/1/

```
/*
HERE IS MY CODE FOR lazy-load -->
 */
    function load(img)
    {
      img.fadeOut(0, function() {
        img.fadeIn(1000);
      });
    }
    $('.lazyload-thumbnail').lazyload({load: load});
    $('.lazyload-youtube').lazyload({trigger: 'mouseover'});
/*
FOR VIDEOS -->
 */
  var figure = $("figure");
        var vid = $("video");
        var cover = $(".img-cover");
        $(figure).hover(function()
                { $(cover).addClass("img-hide");
        }, function()
                { $(cover).removeClass("img-hide");
        }
        );

        [].forEach.call(vid, function (item) {
                item.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverVideo, false);
                item.addEventListener('mouseout', hideVideo, false);
        });

        function hoverVideo(e) {  
                this.play();
        }

        function hideVideo(e) {
                this.pause();
        }
```

I need to stop playing video on mouseout, and play it again on hover.

Theare is a problem with Lazy-load-any and html comments that it uses. 
jQuery cant see code with it, i guess.

Also, this video playing not cause of hover -> video **autoplay**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because the video is being loaded dynamically by lazy load. You have to use event delegation [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

I created a top most parent div with class `main` which is used for event delegation and gave the video an id `myVideo`. Like this

```
$('.main').on('mouseover', '#myVideo', function(){
    $(this).get(0).play()
}).on('mouseout', '#myVideo', function(){
    $(this).get(0).pause();
});
```

In order to get a reference of the video element you should use [`get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/p42q12cm/7/)

Hope this helps.